# Run nuxt 3 client side rendered app with node_env=production

Tags: nuxt.js, nuxtjs3

I don't quite understand, how I can run a nuxt3 app with `NODE_ENV=production`.
I'm executing `nuxt generate` to build my static output directory. That works well, but when I install my dependencies on a server using `yarn install` + `NODE_ENV=production` (to use prod .env, etc.), I get the error `nuxt: command not found`.

Since nuxt3 adds the nuxt dependency as devDependency this is not suprising, but I don't understand, how I should deploy my app.

Installing all devDependencies before running `nuxt generate`? That doesn't seem right. Adding nuxt as normal dependency seems to be a suitable solution, but then I'm wondering why nuxt is added as devDependency per default.

EDIT: The error occurs already when I run `yarn install` since nuxt is doing a `nuxt prepare` command after installing, which fails.

Answer (score 0):

`nuxt generate` isn't meant to built just your static output directory, it generates your whole site as a static bundle, leaving out Nuxt's Nitro server component completely.

If you wish to run your Nuxt app on a Node server in production, you'll want to run `nuxt build` instead and on your production server run `nuxt start`